# Using MEF with the Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, mef, enterprise-library

I'm trying to override the default Unity Container behavior for the Enterprise Library so that I can use my MEF container. There are a few resources with explanations of how to do this but I'm just not getting it:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobbrum/archive/2009/06/23/enterprise-library-5-0-some-architecture-changes.aspx
- http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/90505-silverlight-integration-pack/suggestions/1284693-mef-configurator-for-enterprise-library-container
- http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/261443

There is also this post on SO but the code does not compile because `LogWriter` is protected. I assume this referred to an old version:

- [.net Mef with Enterprise Library 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637678/net-mef-with-enterprise-library-5-0)

What I understand is that I need to use the `CommonServiceLocator` for my MEF container and then attach this to the Enterprise Library container. Here's what I have for my container configurator:

```
public class MefContainerConfigurator : IContainerConfigurator, IServiceLocator
{
    [Import] private CatalogExportProvider provider;

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();   
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType)
    {
        return provider.GetExportedValue<Type>();
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>()
    {
        return provider.GetExportedValue<TService>();
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>(string key)
    {
        return provider.GetExportedValue<TService>(key);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>()
    {
        return provider.GetExportedValues<TService>();
    }

    public void RegisterAll(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in my bootstrapper:

```
var configurator = new MefContainerConfigurator();
// Does this line read the Enterprise Library configuration from the app.config?
IConfigurationSource cs = new SystemConfigurationSource();

EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer(configurator, cs);
```

I think maybe I need to make use of the `LogWriterImpl` and `ExceptionManagerImpl` classes as these have constructors which accept configuration. My questions at this point would be:

- How do I retrieve the configuration from the `IConfigurationSource` and feed it into the constructors for the `LogWriterImpl` and `ExceptionManagerImpl` constructors?
- `EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer` calls `RegisterAll` in my `MefContainerConfigurator`. Is this where I'm supposed to register all of the enterprise library types into the container?
- The methods from the `IServiceLocator` interface that I have left as NotImplemented; I couldn't find a way to use these to return objects from my container. Am I supposed to leave them as not implemented and use the generic methods instead?

**Edit**

I still cannot get this totally right. Based on @Chris Tavares answer, I wrote my `RegisterAll` method in the `MefContainerConfigurator` to iterate through the TypeRegistrations and add them to a container. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to merge these to my `AggregateContainer` that is created in my `Bootstrapper` class so that I can actually use these exports outside of the `ContainerConfigurator`:

```
public void RegisterAll(IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ITypeRegistrationsProvider rootProvider)
{
    var registrations = rootProvider.GetRegistrations(configurationSource);

    foreach (var type in registrations)
    {
        var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();

        builder.ForType(type.ServiceType).Export();

        var cat = new AssemblyCatalog(type.ServiceType.Assembly, builder);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(cat);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

ConfigureAggregateCatalog in Prism bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(RegionNames).Assembly));
    // Module assemblies
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(DataEntryModule).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ReportingModule).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(StatusBarModule).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(SplashScreenModule).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(WelcomeModule).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(AdministrationModule).Assembly));

    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your container configurator is woefully incomplete. You've got one method to implement: RegisterAll, and you didn't implement it.

You don't have to read the raw configuration information from config; instead, what happens is that when you call EnterpriseLibraryContianer.ConfigureContainer, Entlib will spin through the configuration source, pick out all the important bits, and hand you a series of TypeRegistration objects. Those guys give you the type mappings, and the constructor dependencies, etc. Basically all the stuff you need to register the dependencies in your container (in this case, MEF).

So basically what you need to do is write the code that turns the abstract TypeRegistration object into the right configuration for MEF.

Unity isn't special in this regard; it has a configurator as well, and follows the exact same process, so you can look in the entlib code as an example of the kinds of things you'll need to do.

I don't know the MEF apis at all, so unfortunately cannot help you with specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction for the RegisterAll method. See my edit for the revised problem, although I don't think you'll be able to help as it's now MEF specific.